# URL change with .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, get

I want to change URL in .htaccess but I don't know how to do anyone can help me please.

**RewriteRule profile/(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1**

**My URL : http://localhost/profile/swatalk**

**Want to make : http://localhost/swatalk**

If this is possible, Thank you all :)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

Comment: I saw it but I don't understand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Line 1: `(.*)` matches any characters. it makes `/profile/(.*)` redirect to `(.*)` permanently.

Line 2: check if the request uri not matches any existing file

Line 3: check if the request uri not matches any existing directory

Line 4: then rewrite the request uri to `/profile.php?name=$1`, `$1` is the backreference to `(.*)`

The above rule makes `http://localhost/profile/swatalk` redirect to `http://localhost/swatalk`, which is handled by `/profile.php?name=swatalk`

Comment: Thank you so much for explain you are a king this is worked <3